# Category Flat Data Problem

Tags: fatal-error

When I go to "Index management" and try to process show message "There was a problem reindexing process" why?

When i had problem I try to resolve with many magento forum for support with "Category Flat Data"
Note: I Look at Magento forum that go to var/locks, after clear all but it do not process.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what fatal error showing?

Comment: We can't really tell what's wrong just by looking at the screenshot. You should look in your var/report folder.

Comment: You may want to perform the reindex with SSH instead of from the Admin Panel as it works better with SSH and it will give you more details if there's any errors.